# Testing iron-session `withIronSessionSsr` that uses `context` in NextJs, React, and Jest

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ts-jest

So I have this NextJs utility file function below that returns an imported function. Then that imported function accepts a handler, that uses context, as an argument.

```
import { ironSessionUtil } from './anotherUtil'

const checker = () =>
  ironSessionUtil(({ req }) => {
    const { user } = req.session
    if (!user) {
      return {
        redirect: { destination: '/welcome', permanent: false }
      }
    }

    return { props: { details: user.details } }
  })

export default checker
```

So far I've tried just calling the method but it returns an `Async Function`.

```
it('should return props', () => {
  const result = checker()
  console.log('result >> ', result)
})
```

This returns:

`[AsyncFunction: nextGetServerSidePropsHandlerWrappedWithIronSession]`

I've been scouring the web on how to test this. Would you suggest refactors to make this more testable? Or do you know how this can be done in Jest?

Comment: Hello! I found this question while trying to solve the same issues.  Im on a day off but wanted to drop a comment so I can get in touch with you later about this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're generally asking how to test API routes that have with-iron-session wrapped around them, as that's what I'm working on, and I found your question.  I found this [resource](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session/issues/130), which gave me clues to a possible solution.

**Here's what I did:**
For context, I am using the NextJS pages router for my API routes, and I am wrapping all authenticated routes using [withIronSessionApiRoute()](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session)

The main refactor I did in my code was to export the actual API route function from a separate file.  I stored this file in my /lib folder to keep it out of the API routes.

```
//lib/authApiRoute.js
export async function authRoute(req,res) {
    //put your code for testing here.  I have an example of checking credentials.
    if (!req.session || !req.session.user) {
        res.send({ message: 'not authorized' }, { status: 401 });
        return;
    }
    //and so on...
}
```

Then I imported that function in the actual API route, and perform the wrapping with iron session here.  Iron session doesn't need to be tested, but it would be important to perform integration testing here.

```
//pages/api/authRoute.js
import { withIronSessionApiRoute } from 'iron-session/next';
import { sessionOptions } from 'PATH_TO_SESSION_OPTIONS';
import { authRoute } from 'lib/authApiRoute';

export default withIronSessionApiRoute(authRoute,sessionOptions);
```

Now, with the Jest testing, I can use a package like [node-mocks-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http) to create the session information I want to respond to, and test the code to see how it responds.

```
import { createMocks } from 'node-mocks-http';
import { authRoute } from '../../../lib/authApiRoute';
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

describe("Auth request", () => {
    it('should block unauthorized requests.', async () => {
        var {req, res} = createMocks({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/user/getStudents'
        }, {});
        await getStudents(req,res);
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(401);
    });
    it('should block requests with session, but no user.', async () => {
        var {req, res} = createMocks({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/user/getStudents',
            session: {}
        }, {});
        await getStudents(req,res);
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(401);
    });
    it('should allow auth requests with a user', async () => {
        var {req, res} = createMocks({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/user/getStudents',
            session: {user: { isLoggedIn:true } }
        }, {});
        await getStudents(req,res);
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

Going forward, I know I will have design a way to test that the api route in an integration setting, but separating out the route after authentication is a big win for me, as I can automate all of that in Jest now.